# how to validate Phone Number using IntlPhoneField in dart/flutter? different countries have different number number of digits

Tags: flutter, dart, phone-number

This is My ResuableWidget:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:intl_phone_field/intl_phone_field.dart';
import 'package:intl_phone_field/phone_number.dart';
import 'package:phone_number/phone_number.dart' as number;

import '../Theme/colors.dart';

class ReusableMobNoDropDownMenu extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController? mobileNumberController;
  final bool? readonly;
  final void Function(PhoneNumber)? onchange;
  Future<String?> Function(PhoneNumber?)? validator;
  final String? hintText;
  ReusableMobNoDropDownMenu(
      {this.readonly,
      this.hintText,
      this.validator,
      this.mobileNumberController,
      this.onchange});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IntlPhoneField(
        validator: validator,
        readOnly: readonly == null ? false : true,
        controller: mobileNumberController,
        showCountryFlag: true,
        inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],
        autofocus: false,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
        cursorColor: Colors.black,
        flagsButtonMargin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
        dropdownIconPosition: IconPosition.trailing,
        autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
        decoration: const InputDecoration(
            isDense: true,
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 10, 0, 16),
            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: lightGrey, width: 2.0),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(17))),
            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: lightGrey, width: 2.0),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(17)))),
        initialCountryCode: 'PK',
        onChanged: onchange);
  }
}
```

This is my fcLoginView where i'm using it.

```
Consumer<FCLoginProvider>(builder: (context, value, child) {
                      return ReusableMobNoDropDownMenu(
                        mobileNumberController: value.mobileController,
                        onchange: (val) {
                          val;
                          value.setNumber(val);
                        },
                        validator: (phone) async {
                          await value.validator(phone!);
                        },
                      );
                    }),
```

This is the provider

```
import 'package:intl_phone_field/phone_number.dart' as intl;
import 'package:phone_number/phone_number.dart';

bool _validNumber = false;
  intl.PhoneNumber number =
      intl.PhoneNumber(countryISOCode: "", countryCode: "", number: "");

bool getValidate() {
    if (_isChecked == true &&
        number.number.isNotEmpty &&
        _validNumber == true) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
  Future<void> validator(intl.PhoneNumber phoneNumber) async {
    final countryLetter = phoneNumber.countryISOCode;
    final countryCode = phoneNumber.countryCode;
    final onlyNumber = phoneNumber.number;
    final completenumber = phoneNumber.completeNumber;

    /// using the phone Number

    final phoneNumberUtil = PhoneNumberUtil();
//validating
    final validate = await phoneNumberUtil.validate(completenumber,
        regionCode: countryLetter);
    print("Validate : $validate");
    _validNumber = validate;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

I'm trying to validate using the these packages:

```
import 'package:intl_phone_field/phone_number.dart' as intl;
import 'package:phone_number/phone_number.dart';
phone_number: ^1.0.0
  libphonenumber: ^2.0.2
  intl_phone_number_input: ^0.7.3+1
intl_phone_field: ^3.1.0
```

tried different ways, but not suceeded yet.

I tried to get the validation using this method.
It work to some extend but facing problem. Different countries have different number of digits in the phone number.
i'm using intlPhoneField for the phone field which have default validator,
and using phone_number (method phoneNumberUtil) package to validate the output.
Now, with some countries, intlPhoneField is saying, number is not valid, but phoneNumberUtil is saying number is valid and vice versa.

**what I want?**
I tried to use libphonenumber package, but didin't suceeded.
If you have any mehod method, which can validate the number on the basic of country and can return  the result in the boolean. So that, I can store the validation result to some variable and can use that variable at some other places